# Sequential AJAX call inside loop using jQuery.Deferred()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm having a loop, inside the loop there is an AJAX call. For each loop AJAX returns a value. I want sequential loop one after another only when AJAX request is completed. I've done this using `async:false` but this method hangs my other code.

I want to do with `$.Deferred()`

This is my code:

```
function CheckAvailability(Display) {
    var Status = "";

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "myurl",
        dataType: "json",
        data: { "Display": Display },
        async: false,
        success: function (result) {
            Status = result[0].Availability;
        }
    });

    return Status;
}

$(DisplayData).each(function (index, Display) {
    var Availability = CheckAvailability(Display) === 'Yes' ? '' : '<span style="margin-left:10px"><i class="fa fa-exclamation text-danger"></i></span>';
    var Name = Display.Name + Availability;

    console.debug(Name);
});
```

I want output like:

```
Display1 Yes
Display2 No
Display3 No
Display4 Yes
```

Comment: Just a note: If you need to use `async:false` when making AJAX calls it's very likely you're doing something wrong.

Comment: It's much better practice to aggregate all the data in to a single request. Then you can distribute the response among all the relevant elements in the UI. This is for both performance and scalability reasons.